# Laravel disable controller action layout

Tags: laravel

Is there a way to disable layout for certain controller method?

Im using something like `$this->layout = null` ,yet it still render the layout

The view im rendering obviously have a layout associate with it, i just wonder is it possbile to disable the layout from within controller method, without need to modify the blade file itself

Here is the controller:

```
class PurchaserController extends \BaseController 
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->layout = null;
        return View::make('purchasers.index');    
    }
}
```

The view:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
   Content
@stop
```

Im using Laravel 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove

```
@extends('layouts.master')
```

from your view. That will prevent the view from loading.

Also - if you are using the @extends - then you dont actually need `$this->layout()` in your controller at all

Edit:

*" i just wonder is it possbile to disable the layout from within controller method, without need to modify the blade file itself"*

The idea is you do it either entirely from the controller, or entirely from the blade file. Not both together.

Comment: ah ic, laravel doc dosent give thorough documentation about the view/blade..thx